# How to SELECT the Unknown Set from a Known Set?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, relational-database

Sorry if I wrongly stated the problem in the title. An example will be more clear:

Suppose that I have `Users`, `Topics`and `Questions` tables in the database. Each user first selects some `topics` then sets the number of `questions` for each topic and the algorithm creates an examination from the `Questions` that were **not previously solved by the user.** Then the question arises:

- What is the best way to `SELECT` the unsolved questions in the database?

Naturally, I first created a Associative table for *questions solved by an user* with `UserId` and `QuestionId` but then I thought it is better to store the *unsolved questions* instead of *solved questions* since I need to `SELECT` the unsolved ones.

Since that population is larger, let me to summarize the problem with two questions:

1. Is it an overload for the database if I use the `solvedQuestions` table for checking a question whether it was solved or not, every time?
2. Is it ok to insert all questions as unsolved for a new user If I use the `unsolvedQuestions` table? (The number of questions in the future scares me a lot.)
3. Do you have any better design?

Any help will be appreciated.

(By the way, I'm using Entitiy Framework Code First Approach if it matters which I don't think so.)

Comment: This is really an SQL question, not a database question.  You need to understand `IN` and `NOT IN`.  1) No, it is not an "overload".  2) No, that is really stupid.  We store Facts not non-Facts.  3) @Brian has provided the answer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name.  1) For those who understand the question (a) it is generic SQL (b) the platform is irrelevant.  2) Separately, sure, there are several freeware and vapourware offerings that use the term SQL without conforming to the SQL requirement, which is fraud.  Eg. if your "sql" "platform" does not have `IN` or does not support subqueries, it isn't SQL.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA: even the commercial offerings don't support all of the SQL standard - the level of support for standard SQL is very different even with the most basic SQL operations (including the commercial offerings). So it is good to know which concrete DBMS is being used. When creating a question with the `sql` tag there is even a notice that asks to provide that information.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
1) In this Q&A, we are concerned about (a) SQL `IN`, which (b) requires a subquery.  Those are standard SQL requirements.  Try not to get distracted with issues ouside that scope.  
2) *the level of support for standard SQL is very different even with the most basic SQL operations* is patently false.  It is the common excuse made by the pretend-sql crowd, to justify their non-compliance.  If you wish to get educated about the subject, please open a new question, and post an example of a genuine SQL platform that does not comply.

Comment: Corrected incorrect tag deletion.  The question is about a relational database (see example given by OP), and SQL is the Relational database language.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA: you could run a simple `where (a,b) in (select x,y from ...)` in various DBMS to see how the seemingly "simple" IN condition works.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name.  Since it is for your benefit (irrelevant to the Q&A and to me), you do the running.  Evidently, the seeker; the responder; and I, have no problem at all coding SQL.  As requested previously, as per SO guidelines, if you need help with "platform" differences; pretend-sqls, and now, simple coding for more than one column in a subquery or `IN`, please ask a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188054/discussion-between-performancedba-and-a-horse-with-no-name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `SolvedQuestions` table like what you describe, and use `Not In()` logic to look for unsolved questions.  That way I don't have to create a bunch of new records every time I add a user.  Or a question.

What do you mean by "an overload" in your first question?

Comment: I mean checking a `question` whether it is in the table `SolvedQuestions` or not for every request in different times is overload but the `Not In()` logic answers it probably.

Comment: I see.  I expect that, with the proper indices, this approach will perform quite acceptably.

Comment: For the ones who want to implement `Not In()` in entity framework see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7182474/4176989)